# Merging 2 CSV files in 1 WORD file

Tags: csv, merge, ms-word

Is it possible to merge 2 CSV-files in one Word-document?

FYI:
The CSV's are rendered from a database. The database contains information about reservations in a hotel. There is one CSV with the general information (booker, room number, etc) and one CSV with the options (like filled fridge, dog).

First there is a confirmation to the booker, therefor I need one CSV, so that's no problem.

But to create the bill I need to combine both CSV documents.

The CSV files looks as followed (general CSV)

```
Reservation_id | Name | Address | Roomnumber ...
```

The other one (options)

```
Reservation_id | option | price
```

In the first CSV the reservation-id is unique, in the second file, it is not. It can be possible that one id is present for 7 times.

So: is it possible to add both CSV's in one Word-file?

Answer (score 0):

there are two possible ways of doing this either load both csv files to any list of language you are using then generate another list by joining both list using id for each iteration of list 1. 
another best possible tricks is to create csv from database using simple table joining which will be very fast and is efficient way of doing this.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with the first sentence.